# Conditionally add Spring application sibling

Tags: java, spring

I am currently creating a spring application that has a bunch of of application contexts.

```
SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .parent(Parent::class.java).web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
            .child(Child::class.java).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
            .sibling(Sibling::class.java).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
```

What I want to do(and am struggling with) is expose another context if a spring profile is set.

ex. have an admin api open if requested.

It seems simple enough by just adding another sibling that has a `@Profile` annotation on it, and that sort of works. Only issue is that I get an exception during startup because it can't find any web servlet beans if the profile is not active.

I've tried to add the sibling in an if statement, but the issue with that is that I don't have access to the properties read by spring as it is not yet read/initialized in the main function of the application.

So question is, is there any way around this to maybe add the sibling later on if the profile is set?

Comment: Do you really need to mess around with: `SpringApplicationBuilder` or couldn't you just use `Profiles` & `Configs` like you normally would?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but profiles and configs will not allow me to use multiple ports which is something that I desperately need

Comment: Huh? Other than exhausting ports on your machine, can't think of any benefits there. Only reason is if you want to support HTTP for one controller, & HTTPS for another, but even then nowadays you would use a proxy for that. I think if you would explain why you have that constraint, it wouldn't make any sense out loud.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into spring Boot's Conditionals. You can do a conditional on a ton of other things, and these can be used on Configuration classes and Beans.

I tend to look directly into github because every guide is kinda dumb in that it gives examples of one or two but doesn't give you a list of what is available.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition

Hope this helps, good luck!

If you solve it, please post your resolution :)